# Ошибка Error using horzcat в матлабе

Tags: matlab

```
X1 = [1;1;1;1];
X2 = cordexch(2,4,'linear');

for k = 1:4
    z1(k) = 70+191*X2(k,1); 
    z2(k) = 45+15*X2(k,2);
end;

load_system('thermo1');
sim('thermo1');

y1 = simout(end,1:end);
y = y1';
X = [X1,z1',z2']
[B,BINT,R,RINT, STATS] = REGRESS(y,X,0.05)
yr = X*B
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in module1 (line 14)
X = [X1,z1',z2']
```

Не понимаю, почему и подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Неизвестно, что у вас получается в результате выполнения команды load_system. Возможно, что переопределяется какая-то из ранее заданных величин X1, z1 или z2. Поэтому и размеры объединяемых в матрицу векторов получаются разные.